# Calculating the difference between 2 times, and then compare the difference to see if it is less than 5 minutes

Tags: c#, .net

I want to calculate the difference between two times and then compare difference is less than 5 MIN..
Please note I want difference in min. using c#.net

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just use the subtraction operator, and use the `Duration` method to get the absolute value

```
DateTime dt1 = ...;
DateTime dt2 = ...;

TimeSpan diff = (dt2 - dt1).Duration();

if (diff.TotalMinutes < 5)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: instead of using Math.Abs, you can also use .Duration() on a timespan like `TimeSpan diff = (dt2 - dt1).Duration();`

Comment: I didn't know that method, thanks for the tip... fixed again ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
 TimeSpan span = firstDate - secondDate;
 return span.TotalMinutes < 5;
```

Comment: This test will return true for "1 hour and 3 minutes"... you have to use TotalMinutes, not Minutes

Comment: @Thomas - yes, I overlooked that portion. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Almost identical to @Thomas, but another method -

Assuming that dt1 is greater than dt2

```
if(dt1.Sutract(dt2).TotalMinutes < 5)
{
    // do
}
```

The primary difference is that it uses the dt1 memory space to perform the subtraction.

Edit: To use the TotalMinutes correction. The substract method is still present in the datetime object though so I'll leave it here.

Comment: Yah, I wasn't even thinking about that for some reason (it was painfully obvious as soon as you commented on your own answer).